# C# Regular Expression excluding a char (!)

Tags: c#, regex

the regular expression below works well:

```
\bG1\b
```

But I would like to adapt it to not find the G1 occurrences if preceded by a !. For example:

```
='Plan1'!G1            --> NOT match!
=G1*G2                 --> MATCH!
='Plan2'!A1+'Plan2'!G1 --> NOT match!
```

**how would this regular expression?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [**negative lookbehind**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8):

> **`(?<!subexpression)`**
>   where *subexpression* is any regular expression pattern. For a match to be successful, *subexpression* must not occur at the input string to the left of the current position. However, any substring that does not match *subexpression* is not included in the match result.

So, use

```
(?<!!)\bG1\b
^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!!)%5CbG1%5Cb&i=%3D%27Plan1%27!G1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20--%3E%20NOT%20match!%0D%0A%3DG1*G2%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20--%3E%20MATCH!%0D%0A%3D%27Plan2%27!A1%2B%27Plan2%27!G1%20--%3E%20NOT%20match!)

[image]